# Prove the following identity for the Apéry constant

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Perhaps this kind of integral is well knonw, or can be easily deduced from other. I don't know it but I would like to see the computation of this to refresh the computation of iterated integrals. I was inspired to change the factors of those integrals in the **Wikipedia Page** for **Apéry 's constant**. Firht I tried modify those integrals writting some factors $\sqrt{x}$. After with factors $1-x^2$ and computing with the [online calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) of  **Wolfram Alpha** one find with the code

> $\displaystyle{\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1 (1-y^2)(1-t^2)/(1-xyz)
> \,dx\,dy\,dz\,dt}$

an integral involving the cited constant.

I am assuming that these families were well known , because was easy to find those identities by similarity, when one modify such integrands as I've said. See also this **MathWorld Page** for the [Apéry's constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AperysConstant.html), truly those formulas and identites are more complicated than my question, thus the kind of integral that

> **Question.** Show us how to prove 
>   $$\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{(1-y^2)(1-t^2)}{1-xyz}dxdydzdt=\frac{1}{36}(24\zeta(3)+9-2\pi^2).$$
>    **Thanks in advance.**

Since the idea was easy, see comments for other example, it is easy that it was in the literature.

Also you are welcome to answer the following optional question,

> **Question (Optional)** Can you find a integral now involving at least a factor $\sqrt{\text{variable}}$ of previous variables $x,y,z,\ldots$, to get an identity, as the previous, for $\zeta(3)$?

Comment: try to make more spaces between the characters.

Comment: int_0^1int_0^1int_0^1 (1-y^2)/(1-xyz)dx dy dz

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{1-y^2}{1-xyz}dxdydz=\zeta(3)+\frac{3}{8}- \frac{\pi^{2}}{12} $$

Comment: Very thanks much @nospoon

Comment: @user243301   You're welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the $t$ integral is trivial, we will not bother with it and just calculate

$$
I=\int_{[0,1]^3} dx dy dz  \frac{1-y^2}{1-xyz}
$$

the first integration is standard an yields (let's take $z$)
$$
I=\int_{[0,1]^2} dx dy (1-y^2)\frac{\log(1-xy)}{xy}
$$

now, using one of the standard properties of [Polylogarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm), namely $z \text{Li}_{\nu}'(z)=\text{Li}_{\nu-1}$, this becomes

$$
I=-\int_{[0,1]} dy (1-y^2)\frac{\text{Li}_2(y)}{y}
$$

Using the above mentioned property again this yields

$$
I=\text{Li}_3(1)+\int_{[0,1]} dy y\text{Li}_2(y)
$$

the last integral is easily tackeld using integration by parts with $y=u'$ and $v=\text{Li}_2(y)$. After putting back in the limits of integration this becomes

$$
I=\text{Li}_3(1)+\frac{1}{2}\text{Li}_2(1)+\frac{3}{8}
$$

which is equal to

> $$
> I=\zeta(3)-\frac{\pi^2}{12}+\frac{3}{8}
> $$

which gives us the announced result if we take a factor $2/3$ into account which stems from the integral over $t$

Comment: how do you introduce it : $Li_2(y) = $  ??

Comment: Very thanks much now I am studying your proof and the other user. Thanks to you since now we can study your apporach.

Comment: I've decided to grant to you the Polylog badge, here is:  $\bullet$ **Polylog**. Then I say to you that congratulations, since is a golden badge and is unique.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}
{\pars{1 - y^{2}}\pars{1 -t^{2}} \over 1 - xyz}\,\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z\,\dd t =
{2 \over 3}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}
{1 - y^{2} \over 1 - xyz}\,\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z
\\[5mm] = &\
{2 \over 3}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}
\pars{x^{n}y^{n}z^{n} - x^{n}y^{n + 2}z^{n}}\,\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z =
{2 \over 3}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\bracks{{1 \over \pars{n + 1}^{3}} -
{1 \over \pars{n + 1}^{2}\pars{n + 3}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{2 \over 3}\,\zeta\pars{3} +
\left.{2 \over 3}\,\totald{}{\mu}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{n + \mu}\pars{n + 3}}
\,\right\vert_{\ \mu\ =\ 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
{2 \over 3}\,\zeta\pars{3} +
{2 \over 3}\,\ \underbrace{%
\totald{}{\mu}\bracks{\Psi\pars{\mu} - \Psi\pars{3} \over \mu - 3}
_{\ \mu\ =\ 1}}_{\ds{\ {1 \over 24}\pars{9 - 2\pi^{2}}}}\qquad
\pars{~\Psi:\ Digamma Function~}
\\[5px]= &\ \ \bbox[#ffe,15px,border:1px dotted navy]
{\ds{{2 \over 3}\,\zeta\pars{3} + {1 \over 4} - {1 \over 18}\,\pi^{2}}}
\end{align}

Comment: Very nice your trick with the derivative and the Digamma Function. Many thanks.

Comment: @user243301 You're welcome.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:  I know this isn't as slick as the answer using polylogs but I always liked this approach to any integration with $\frac{1}{1-xyz}$ from [0,1].  Also I should note I got this approach from the book "Proofs from the Book"  in the section "Three Times $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$", I think is the name.  They use this approach to show $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

The t portion of the integral can be done separately using Fubini's theorem so noting that $\int_0^1(1-t^2)dt=t-\frac{t^3}{3}|_0^1=\frac{2}{3} $ this will be a prefactor that I will insert at the end.

So the remaining integral is:

$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{1-y^2}{1-xyz} dxdydz$.  We can rewrite this into two integrals:  $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-xyz} dxdydz-\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{y^2}{1-xyz} dxdydz$.  Now since we're working on $[0,1]$ we can use the following geometric series $\frac{1}{1-xyz}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(xyz)^n$.  So the first integral becomes $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \sum_{n=0}^\infty (xyz)^n dxdydz$, exchanging the integrals and the sum and breaking up into three integrals we have, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^1 x^ndx \int_0^1 y^n dy \int_0^1 z^n dz$ this is simply, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}|_0^1)(\frac{y^{n+1}}{n+1}|_0^1)(\frac{z^{n+1}}{n+1}|_0^1)$ = $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)^3}$ or reindexing we have $\zeta(3)$.  The second integral can be tackled in the same way as the first changing everything into sums just as before we have now -$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^1 x^ndx \int_0^1 y^{n+2} dy \int_0^1 z^n dz$ or $-\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}|_0^1)(\frac{y^{n+3}}{n+3}|_0^1)(\frac{z^{n+1}}{n+1}|_0^1)=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+3)(n+1)^2}=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+2)n^2}$.  Using partial fractions this becomes: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty -\frac{1}{2n^2}-\frac{1}{4(n+2)}+\frac{1}{4n}=-\frac{1}{2} \zeta(2) - \frac{1}{4}(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+2)}-\frac{1}{n})=-\frac{\pi^2}{12}+\frac{3}{8}$.  Where I used that I know what the zeta function is at 2 (it's $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$) and also that the last set of sums telescopes to $\frac{3}{2}$.  So grouping all this together we get $\zeta(3)-\frac{\pi^2}{12}+\frac{3}{8}$.  Multiplying this by $\frac{2}{3}$ from the t integral gives the desired result.

Comment: Very thanks much for your effort and great explanation.

Comment: No problem!  Thank you for posting this I had never seen this integral before and it was fun to solve!

Comment: Very thanks much **mike**. You and previous user have the merit. 
I am currently out of the world of the university, and this is the only site in where can I refresh my maths. This site give me a lot this year, you and all users. If I have a doubt if it was in the literature with the purpose to din't disturb anyone. As you say, you don't know, I say thanks. On the ther hand, as I've said you and the other user give me lot when you answer my questions, then I can say to you that to me does not shake my hand to share these ideas that I think genuine with this community. Thanks one more time.

Comment: Who down votes an answer weeks later with no explanation?  This site is so strange sometimes..  If there is something wrong with my answer I would love to hear it.

Comment: Thanks one more time. I hope that you do not have more problems.